# Need help do-while loop program? (C++)

Tags: c++, average, do-while

I am trying to create a program that will take user inputs(marks) and output the average of these marks to a letter grade.
I believe I have succeded in getting the program to calculate the average succesfully, however it will not output the right letter grade?

Any suggestions?
EDIT: Perhaps it is something in the calculations, because my output always gives the percentage as an "F" grade....

```
// Used iomanip to display averages for possible three digit or greater answers.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Set up my program using only main()
int main()
{
    //Created the variable 'mark' so the user input can be stored and tested in the do-while condition.
    //Variable 'sum' and 'average' to calculate mark and then be tested against letter grades.
    //'counter' used to keep track of number of terms being averaged.
    double mark=0, sum=0, average=0;
    int counter=-1;

    // Do-while statement to test the loop. Gets input from user, and tests whether it is a a valid letter grade.
    // Marks below 0 or above 100 will test true and loop back re-promting the user for another mark.
    // If tested condition is false, then if statements then test the mark and output the letter grade.

    cout << "Please enter marks to calculate average, and enter -1 to stop and find letter equivalence. " << endl;

    do
    {
        if ( mark < 0 || mark > 100 )
        {
            cout << "Entered mark is invalid. Please try again, or enter -1 to stop and find letter equivalence. " << endl;
            break;
        }

        sum = sum + mark;
        counter++;
        cin >> mark;

    }
    while ( mark != -1 );

    average = sum / counter ;

    //What happens when above statement is false...
    if (mark >= 90)
        {
            cout << "The average of "<<setprecision(2)<<average<<"% is equivalent to a letter grade of A+ ";
        }
    else if (mark >=80)
        {
            cout << "The average of "<<setprecision(2)<<average<<"% is equivalent to a letter grade of A ";
        }
    else if (mark >=70)
        {
            cout << "The average of "<<setprecision(2)<<average<<"% is equivalent to a letter grade of B ";
        }
    else if (mark >=60)
        {
            cout << "The average of "<<setprecision(2)<<average<<"% is equivalent to a letter grade of C ";
        }
    else if (mark >=50)
        {
            cout << "The average of "<<setprecision(2)<<average<<"% is equivalent to a letter grade of D ";
        }
    else
        {
            cout << "The average of "<<setprecision(2)<<average<<"% is equivalent to a letter grade of F ";
        }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to consider:

1. Your grades assignment should consider the `average` and not `marks`. If you use marks, then the last entered value which is `-1` to exit your do while loop will be used to grade which will always result in F grade.
2. Add `endl` to all your `cout` statements after the `do-while` loop. The output stream may have been buffered and this can cause the cout statements to not appear on your monitor. `endl` will flush the output stream.

For eg.
`cout << "The average of "<<setprecision(2)<<average<<"% is equivalent to a letter grade of A+ " << endl;`

Comment: For part one of you suggestion, how can I achieve this when my average calculation comes after the do-while loop? I attempted this in compiler, and the result was no output?! Thanks

Comment: It seems like homework to me. I would not provide the code. If your editor supports debugging, then step over your code and carefully watch the variables. If not, add debug statements to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: I am new to the debugger, but after a few tries getting to grips with it, I managed to do it and realized my pitiful mistake D:
Thank you for you patience, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your `if` statements.  I'd wager that you're always seeing the correct average is equivalent to an F.

Comment: What would you do to stop my correct average always being 'F'?
I am not sure how to compare the average with my if statements below, because in my average calculation is after my while statement?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your loop, `mark` is always `-1`. So all the tests fail, you fall through to the `else` clause, and output an F. The fix is to test `average`, not `mark`.

Comment: How can I test average when the calculation for my average is outside my loop, and therefore can not be tested?

Comment: No, I mean in the `if`/`else if` tree that outputs the average.

Comment: The if/else if tree is there to determine whether the user input is valid.... The if statement is testing if the user put a valid mark in. I am not sure why I would test average instead?

Comment: First off, apologies, I know what you meant, a very silly mistake.
Thank you for you patience, really appreciate it!